# How to override Magento 2 core files?

Tags: magento2, overrides, pdf, core

I want to customize the invoice PDF, so I believe I need to edit Magento 2 core files, please guide me how to achieve this task.

My purpose is customize the invoice PDF

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using **`preference`** tag.

inside **`app/etc/di.xml`** file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Invoice" type="Package\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Invoice" />  

</config>
```

You can create invoice.php file inside `Package\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml` folder and changes core data.

Thanks.